# Load all pages scrolled to top of the body instead of my ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a main menu item inside of my base template which resides outside of my `ng-view` container. I would like for my links to work so that whenever I change pages between them, the pages load scrolled on top instead of the `ng-view` nested within my body and outside of my main menu.

It should be noted that when loading a view directly instead of through a link, the view starts on top, as I desire.

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <search />
      <login />
      <!-- more main menu stuff -->
    </header>
    <div ng-view="" class="content">
      <!-- This link should redirect me to /profile *and* start on top of my body! -->
      <a ng-href="#/profile/john">John</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

PS - The main menu is outside of my `ng-view` and directly on my base template so it easily resides on all my views.

Comment: @NewDev I did not know about it! Post as answer so I'll properly kudos you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`autoscroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#usage) param with `ng-view` to make this work.